# RAILS + JQuery and Radion_BUTTON

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 radio_butto_tag ( shown below)

```
<label>Selection :</label><br>
    <label>Randomly</label>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:choice, 'Randomly', true )%>
    <label>Number of ATGC specified</label>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:choice,'No_of_ATGC')%>
```

If the user clicked Number of ATGC button, what will happen is it will then show number_field asking users how many A's T's G's and C's they would like to have. I want this `number_field` to show **only when users** clicked the `radio_button`. But i have no idea how to do so. Can someone guide me through ? New to javascripts rails and all

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

#### wrap your text filed inputs:

```
<div class="atgc_fields hidden">
  <%= f.input .....%>
  ....
  ....
   Or 
  <%= input_tag ...%>
   ...
  ...
</div>
```

#### In css

```
.hidden{
 display:none;
}
```

javascript:

```
$.ready(function(){

 $('input:radio[name="choice"]').change(function(){
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('.atgc_fields').removeClass('hidden');
       }
       else{
         $('.atgc_fields').addClass('hidden');
         $(".atgc_fields input[type=text]").each(function() {
         $(this).val(''); //reset the values of input fields (if any)
         });
        }
     });

})
```

Comment: Hi Muntasim. Thanks alot for the solution. But does can this code call my function ? 

For example :
After the user clicked Number of ATGC specified radio button , then the number_field for A , T , G, C needs to show. After the user entered the values for ATGC , i wan to pass those values to a function defined in my applicationcontroller. Should i do that ( pass values to the function defined in applicationController) in the javascript ?

Comment: you should have another controller to handle it, application controller is not for this type of task in general. If you are really new to rails then please follow:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: oh so i can't use the jQuery anymore ?

Comment: why not!, you have to have some basics about rails then you can play with it. please read the book for couple of days. It will guide you through